# Querying the database with double or check in AND check

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been trying to query the database with this line of code:

```
$query_check = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM chat 
                            WHERE sent_by_id || sent_to_id = '$user' 
                               AND sent_by_id || sent_to_id = '$friend_id'");
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is check if one of two tables poses first variable AND if one of two tables poses second variable. Now I know there is an operator OR but it wouldn't work in this case as you can imagine.

So the ending result should be something like this:

```
1,2  
2,1  
1,1  
2,2
```

but I get results like this:

```
1,1  
1,2  
2,2  
1,1  
2,1  
4,1  
3,1
```

and so on.

Comment: @nl-x actually it is a logical or: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

Comment: @PerfectPixel, funny. I never see that one being used... do you happen to know if `||` has the same different precedence to `or` like in PHP ?

Comment: @nl-x by documentation they seem equivalent

Comment: well MySQL has has both `||` and `or` on the same level (see [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)). In PHP they are on a different level (see [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)).

Comment: Actually `||` is the concatenation operator when in ANSI mode (or the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) is enabled) so better to avoid it. Use `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
WHERE (sent_by_id = '$user' AND sent_to_id = '$friend_id') 
   OR (sent_by_id = '$friend_id' AND sent_to_id = '$user')
```

The parenthesis are there for clarity. Not needed really.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do the job. :D

Comment: `WHERE (sent_by_id, sent_to_id) IN ((...), (...))` would work in MySQL, no?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, but it yields inefficient plans (not sure if it has been corrected in 5.6). So better safe than sorry.

Comment: Absolutely, and I *have* heard something about tuple comparisons being inefficient too, although I didn't know/remember if it concerned tuples of *constants* as well as any other tuples (and hoped it didn't).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with brackets and use OR operator

```
$query_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (sent_by_id = '$user' OR sent_to_id = '$user') AND (sent_by_id = '$friend_id' OR sent_to_id = '$friend_id')");
```

Comment: Kinda hoped that would work, I mean it seems logical, but I still get the same result.

Comment: This seems correct, too. And equivalent to my answer (unless you have messages from a user to itself.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_check = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        * -- In stead of *, you can just use: sent_by_id, sent_to_id
    FROM
        chat
    WHERE
        (sent_by_id = '$user' OR sent_to_id = '$user')
        AND (sent_by_id = '$friend_id' OR sent_to_id = '$friend_id')
");
```